# How to set a data type of "worksheets.cells" as a variable in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing a program for my company to update a spreadsheet of training data. I reference arbitrary cells a few times using the ".cells" function and want to make "MasterSheet.Cells" and "UpdatingSheet.Cells" variables. I'm getting a 424 error after the 6th line of code. Is the cell not a range data type?

```
    Set MasterSheet = wbMaster.Worksheets("Master Sheet")
    Set NewSheet = wbNewPractice.Worksheets("My Teams Learning") 
    Set UpdatingSheet = wbMaster.Worksheets("Updating Sheet")

     Dim MstrShtCell As Range
    Dim UpdtShtCell As Range
    
    
    Set MstrShtCell = MasterSheet.Cells
    Set UpdtShtCell = UpdatingSheet.Cells
        
       ' Dim q As Boolean
        
       ' If IsEmpty(UpdtShtCell.Value) Then
         '   q = True
      '  End If
        
    Do Until UpdtShtCell(i, j).Value <> "" 'Iterate through entire list of worksheet names
    
        Do Until UpdtShtCell(i, j).Value = MstrShtCell(a, b).Value 'comparing new worksheet name i to master worksheet name a
            
            a = a + 1 'iterates to next name in the column
            
            If IsEmpty(MstrShtCell) Then 'Checks if name exists in the master list
                Call WriteData 'if it does not exist then add it to the master list
                Exit Do 'move to the next step
            End If
        Loop
    
        Do Until UpdatingSheet.Cells(1, y).Value = "Enrolled Content" 'getting the column for the new Training class name
            y = y + 1
        Loop
        
        Do Until UpdatingSheet.Cells(i, y).Value = MasterSheet.Cells(1, b).Value 'getting the master worksheet column for the associated training class
            b = b + 1
        Loop
        
        Do Until UpdatingSheet.Cells(1, y).Value = "Completion Date" 'getting the column for the new training completion date
            y = y + 1
        Loop
        
        If IsEmpty(UpdatingSheet.Cells(i, y)) Then 'Checks if completed or not
            MstrShtCell(a, b).Interior.Color = red
            MstrShtCell(a, b).Value = "Incomplete"
        Else
            If UpdatingSheet.Cells(i, y).Value > UpdatingSheet.Cells(i, (y + 4)).Value Then 'checks if expired or not
                MstrShtCell(a, b).Value = UpdatingSheet.Cells(i, y).Value
                MstrShtCell(a, b).Interior.Color = red
            Else
                MstrShtCell(a, b).Value = UpdatingSheet.Cells(i, y).Value
                MstrShtCell(a, b).Interior.Color = green
                
             End If
        End If

        
        i = i + 1
        a = 2
        b = 1
        y = 1
    
    Loop
        
    
End Sub
```

Comment: You probably don't want or need to assign every cell to a range, but can't see a problem. How did you declare `MasterSheet`?

Comment: ``` Dim wbMaster As Workbook
    Dim wbNewPractice As Workbook
    Dim NewSheet As Worksheet
    Dim UpdatingSheet As Worksheet
    Dim MasterSheet As Worksheet ```

Comment: I'm not getting any error running that top section of code. Are you trying to copy the cells into a memory-based array?

Comment: Which line is the 6th?